# Creating a view and agent in multiple databases

Tags: view, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

The problem I am encountering is that some of the messages are not accessible by the user ID file, I would like to skip these files instead of the agent crashing out. The error message received is as follows:

[image: decryptionError]

Using the view approach if this happened I was able to delete the document temporarily and re-run the agent but if there is a way to skip documents it would be a great help.

Thanks for the help guys.

Ok I have amended the code to a point where I am almost comfortable with it.

Sub Initialize

```
Dim s As New notessession
Dim db As notesdatabase 
Dim view As notesview
Dim doc As notesdocument
Dim nextdoc As notesdocument


Set db = s.currentdatabase
If view Is Nothing Then
    Set view = db.CreateView("Encrypted",{Encrypt="1"})
End If  
Set doc = view.getfirstdocument

On Error Goto ErrorHandler

While Not doc Is Nothing        
nextDocument:
    Set nextdoc = view.getnextdocument(doc)
            'The below loop is mandatory to ensure that all $File entries are unecrypted
    Forall i In doc.items
        If i.isencrypted Then
            i.isencrypted=False 
        End If 
    End Forall

        'Must have at least 1 field encrypted in order to call Encrypt method
    Dim temp As New NotesItem(doc,"tempjunk","temp")
    temp.IsEncrypted=True
    Call doc.encrypt
    Call doc.save(True, False)
        'This portion can now remove the fields relative to encrypting the
        'single token encrypted field.
    Call doc.removeitem("$Seal")
    Call doc.removeitem("$SealData")
    Call doc.removeitem("SecretEncryptionKeys")
    Call doc.removeitem("Encrypt")
    Call doc.removeItem("tempjunk")
    Call doc.save(True, False)
    Set doc = nextdoc 
Wend
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
On Error Resume nextDocument
Exit Sub
```

End Sub

The error handling is not playing nice;

**On Error Resume nextDocument** is showing up as an error.
I have tried suppressing all of the error warnings which seems to attempt to strip the encryption but I think they body of the messages is being destroyed as a result.

Comment: I guess Karl-Henry's example is not ideal. It should say "on error goto errhandler" and in err handler block "resume nextdocument" (instead of "on error resume nextdocument")

Comment: You are correct, I updated my code below.

Answer (score 3):

It is no problem to create an agent in a container database and let that agent access documents in all "target" databases and modify them accordingly - No need to copy that agent to all databases.

Only restriction: If the databases are on another server, then on the server security tab of the target server you have to enter the server with the container database as trusted server.

AND: If your agent runs longer than the allowed maximum run time for agents on the server, then it will be killed prematurely.

There is no need to create views in the target databases, you can use NotesDatabase.Search() to get the corresponding documents in the databases...

Comment: Agreed. The caveat is that if this agent is that if the databases are large and the agent will have to run more than once, then it would be more efficient over the longer term to have the view. But the agent can do that.  It can attempt to open the view, and if it doesn't find the view it can build it and then go back and retry opening it.

Comment: Thank you for the response guys. I am grateful. The reason I am following this route currently is that I have been provided the databases offline and only have a Notes client to run the process on. Please see my amended question with the code I am attempting to create. It may not be possible using only a notes client..

Answer (score 1):

If you have to process all (or almost all) documents in each database, you can use db.AllDocuments. It is more efficient than using db.Search() with an @All formula.

If you want to exclude certain documents, perhaps based on the form name, I would build a list of forms to exclude, and then use IsElement to check each document being processed against that list.

```
Dim exclude List As Boolean
exclude("FormA")=True
exclude("FormB")=True

Set col = db.AllDocuments
Set doc = col.GetFirstDocument()
Do Until doc Is Nothing
    formname = doc.GetItemValue("Form")(0)
    If IsElement(exclude(formname))=False Then
        Call RemoveEncryption(doc)  '*** Your function to remove encryption
    End If
    Set doc = col.GetNextDocument(doc)
Loop
```

Something like that. By the way, you can create the list as any data type. I just choose Boolean as it is a small data type, and that it makes the code easier to read. The IsElement() function just check if the element exists, it does not use the value you set.

You would wrap the code above in a function and call it once per database.

**Appended answer, based on additional info in original question:**

That should not be hard, just add error handling to your code.

Before you start to loop throung the document:

```
On Error Goto errHandler
```

Before you get the next document in the loop:

```
nextDocument:
```

At the end of your code:

```
    Exit Sub
    errHandler:
    Resume nextDocument
End Sub
```

Try that.

Comment: Thankyou Karl-Henry. I like this approach as it negates the need to create a view, I have amended my code, still only running over a single instance as there is an issue which is forcing the agent to fail which I need to fix, hopefully you can assist.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: I think that if I can get the error handling/document skipping working then the solution is sufficient, running in to some problems with the proposed error handling, googled this and what i could find offered the same sort of syntax, I can therefore only surmise it is the placement of the handling that is incorrect in my script, posted above. Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create views by copying them from another database. Say you create a view "Encrypted" in your db with the agent.

Then add a piece of code to get a handle of this view as a NotesDocument:

```
Dim dbThis As NotesDatabase 
Dim viewTemplate As NotesView
Dim docView As NotesDocument

Set dbThis = s.currentDatabase
Set viewTemplate = dbThis.getView("Encrypted")
Set docView = dbThis.Getdocumentbyunid(viewTemplate.Universalid)
```

In the agent loop, test if view Encrypted exists, if not copy the "view template":

```
Set view = db.getview("Encrypted")
If view Is Nothing Then
    Call docView.Copytodatabase(db)
    Set view = db.getview("Encrypted")
End If
```

Finally, if you insist, a similar procedure might be used to copy the agent to all databases, but for me the idea of running the agent in one db sounds better.

**Edited:** In the view of full disclosure - of course you can create a view (I guess that was the original question).

```
If view Is Nothing Then
   Set view = db.Createview("Encrypted", {Encrypt="1"})
End If
```

Or do one-shot dbSearch suggested by Torsten, with a good re-mark of Richard - if you intend to run your code several times - say if encrypted documents might get created again or re-encrypted, rather go for the view.

My method is a bit old fashioned (pre-dates availability of createView) and works well if you need more than selection formula, so you can pre-build a complicated view for re-use.

Performance-wise: whatever method you will choose either creating view using createView or copying from other db or doing dbSearch there is going to be a certain slow-down while the view gets built or dbSearch executes. Karl-Henry's approach will avoid this search/view build, but will be relatively slow if there are not many encrypted documents.

Whichever method you choose - here is a small tip to boost performance. Make your loops like this to release memory as you go; for example, assuming Karl-Henry's approach:

```
Dim doc1 as NotesDocument
Set doc = col.GetFirstDocument()
Do Until doc Is Nothing
    Set doc1 = col.GetNextDocument(doc)
    formname = doc.GetItemValue("Form")(0)
    If IsElement(exclude(formname))=False Then
        Call RemoveEncryption(doc)  '*** Your function to remove encryption
    End If
    ' releasing memory when processing thousands of documents improves performance and avoids crashes
    Delete doc
    Set doc = doc1
Loop
```

Now again, as you are talking *only* about migration (so one shot) of 20+ databases, the speed or implementation details should not be that critical.

Comment: I was wondering, if I was to have an agent that would run over many databases, would it be possible to just create a view through the agent using a selection criteria 'Encrypt="1"' ?

Comment: I updated my post, to reflect this (and maybe give some more ideas)

Comment: Thanks again, this information is very helpful. You are right that the speed isn't as much of a factor here, it is more the automation (not dropping out on errors and multiple databases at once) that is my aim. I will have other users to migrate so there will be bulks of nsfs to handle.